# LOAD DATA INFILE not upload all the lines in a huge file

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I wrote this SQL source:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+exportDataFile+"' INTO TABLE ex_patients_variations FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This source should load to the database a huge file (right now it contain over than 1 million lines, and in the future it could contain billions lines).

The problem is its not load all the lines in the file.

I try to run it some times, and everytime I use this SQL source, it upload different number of lines (between 550,000 to 660,000 lines, when I have more than 1 million lines).

How can I solve it and upload all the file lines in one time to the database?

Answer (score 0):

when it is only for one time you can split the file in some pieces
with

```
split --lines=100000 FILENAME
```

So it will split it in 10 file with 100000 lines each.

also you can test to set the variable **max-allowed-packet=** in my.cnf to a higher value. you must restart the server